# Show progress of Yearling badge?

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if it is possible to show the Yearling badge (and other badges that can be earned multiple times) in a user's profile page?

Currently, no such information is available.

Comment: How would you show the progress for the Yearling as there are 2 independent criteria?  It would mean adding a 2nd progress bar to the tracker.

Comment: To see progress towards the yearling badge, you can use a calendar.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Of course, that's what started this question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 perhaps track rep with the bar, then switch to days once 200+ rep has been earned

Comment: @royhowie I can see that being confusing for anyone who earns 200 rep well before the year is up.  They will see themselves tracking towards the badge, they get the 200 rep and when they think they earned the badge, the progress bar drops to the date criteria.

Comment: How do you know how much reputation you've earned so far in a year?  Is there any way to tell this?